# Declaring arrays: name of the array with spaces

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand a part of my professor's code. He gave an example for a hw assignment but I'm not sure how to understand this part of the code..

Here is the code:

```
void addTask(TaskOrAssignment tasks[], int& taskCount, char *course, char *description, char *dueDate)
{
    tasks[taskCount].course = course;
    tasks[taskCount].description = description;
    tasks[taskCount].dueDate = dueDate;         
    taskCount++;
}
```

Question: Is "`tasks[taskCount].course = course;`" accessing or declaring a location for char course?

I hope I could get this answered and I'm pretty new to this site too.

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed C strings are odd creatures compared to other pointers.

Comment: Why do such professors get to keep their job, while I have to go through "performance review"? Not fair. We really need some Dr Evil quotes to put around the 'C++' in 'C++ class'.

Comment: Yuck. This is being taught? I'm not surprised you can't understand this -- heck, _I_ can barely make heads or tails of it since there are so many unknowns and this style of code is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tasks[taskCount].course = course;
```

Let's break this down a piece at a time. First of all, we are using the assignment operator (=) to assign a value of one variable to another variable.

The right hand side is pretty simple, just the variable named `course` which is declared as a `char*`.

It is assigned to the variable `tasks[taskCount].course`. If you look at the parameters of the method, you can see that `tasks` is declared as an array of `TaskOrAssignment` objects. So `tasks[taskCount]` refers to one of the elements of this array. The `.course` at the end refers to a field named `course` in that object. Assuming that this code compiles, that field is declared as a `char*` in the `TaskOrAssignment` class.

Most likely, both `course` variables represent a string of characters. (This originates from C.) When all is said and done, both `course` and `tasks[taskCount].course` point to the same string buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`course` is a char pointer, it points to the block of memory in stack or heap storing the `'\0'` terminated string.

`tasks[taskCount].course` is also a char pointer, the assignment just lets `tasks[taskCount].course` point to same memory address that `course` does.

Comment: You have absolutely no way of knowing what `course` points to.

Comment: In theory, you are right. char * could point to anything. But from code logic, it looks like string.

Comment: It "looks like" it but half the point is that there is no way of knowing what it _really_ is, what its ownership semantics are, etc. Thus, forming a conclusion about the behaviour of this code is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

`course` is a `char*` (a pointer to `char`). Presumably, the `course` member of `TaskOrAssignment` is also a `char*`. All that line does is assign the value of `course` to the member `course` of the `taskCount`th element in the array.

Presumably, the `course` argument is intended to be a pointer to the first character in a null-terminated C-style string. So after this assignment, the `course` member of the array element will point at that same C-style string. However, of course, the pointer could really be pointing anywhere.